# When to use innerJoin instead of where with Doctrine 2?

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, inner-join, query-builder

I have a user entity and an Event entity. the Users can notify that they want to go to some events.
Those users also have friends who are themselves users (self referencing many to many relation).

I'm looking to retrieve from my database the user' friends who fulfill the following conditions:
They want to go to the same event.
they are nearby each others.

While the second condition is fine, I'm trying to build the best query possible to make sure the first condition is respected.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();


        $qb->select( 'USER', 'FRIENDS' ) // Selecting Me, the user who is asking to retrieve the users matched, and the friends who fill the criterias below
            ->from( 'Entity\User',  'USER' ) // we start with the user
            ->where( 'USER.id = :userId' ) // And I want the user the be me
            ->leftJoin('USER.friends', 'FRIENDS') // I'm going to take all of his friends
            ->innerJoin( 'FRIENDS.eventNotified', 'EVENT' ) //but ONLY the ones that have notified Events ( array collection ov EVENT entity )
            ->leftJoin( 'EVENT.categories', 'c' ) //take events category in order to avoid doing any request when getting the name of the category
            ->leftJoin( 'EVENT.place', 'p' ) // same with  the place where the event occured
            ->andWhere( 
                $qb->expr()->andX(
                    $qb->expr()->between('FRIENDS.latitude', ':minLat', ':maxLat'), //in a defined area
                    $qb->expr()->between('FRIENDS.longitude', ':minLng', ':maxLng'),
                    $qb->expr()->eq('FRIENDS.eventNotified.id', 'USER.eventNotified.id') //I want to select ONLY the friends who have notified they want to go to the same events than me (I have notified the same events as well)
                )
            )
            ->add( 'orderBy', $qb->expr()->sum( 'FRIENDS.latitude - :lat', 'FRIENDS.longitude - :lng' ) );
```

Unfortunately for me, this is not doing what I am looking to do. And I wonder why.
So once I select FRIENDS, I basically want to select ONLY the friends who have notified they want to go to the same events as the ones I have notified too.

So I'm doing an innerJoin to check if the friends (they are user as well) have notified they want to go to events. And then in those friends, I want to select ONLY the ones who are going to the same events as mine `$qb->expr()->eq('FRIENDS.eventNotified.id', 'USER.eventNotified.id')`.

I think there is my problem ... since eventNotified is a collection of the EVENT entity from which,  I am looking to select ONLY the events we both have notified, can I just get rid of the `.id` ? also, I have the feeling this is selecting all of the events when I just want to retrieve the eventsnotified we have in commun. So I believe I should do an innerJoin here somewhere but I can find the right synthax.

Any advice ?

Thanks

Bonus: should I also specify I want to retrieve 'c' and 'p' in the SELECT statement ?

EDIT:

I tried the solution below, but I am getting this error I don't understand. How can I retrieve the complete error message ? (some parts are missing ! )

Code I have tried :

//We only want to return users nearby who are available OR who
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

```
    $qb->select( 'USER', 'FRIENDS' ) // Selecting Me, the user who is asking to retrieve the users matched, and the friends who fill the criterias below
        ->from( 'Entity\User',  'USER' ) // we start with the user
        ->where( 'USER = :user' ) // And I want the user the be me
        ->leftJoin('USER.friends', 'FRIENDS', 'WITH', 'USER.eventNotified = FRIENDS.eventNotified');

    $array = array(
         'user'   => $user
    );

    $qb->setParameters( $array );

    $usersMatched = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException'
>   with message 'SELECT USER, FRIENDS FROM Entity\User USER LEFT JOIN
>   USER.friends FRIENDS WITH USER.eventNotified = FRIENDS.eventNotified
>   WHERE USER = :user' in
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:39Stack
>   trace:#0
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(429):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError('SELECT USER, FR...')#1
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(686):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->semanticalError('Invalid PathExp...',
>   Array)#2
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(240):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->_processDeferredPathExpressions(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\SelectStatement))#3
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(304):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->getAST()#4 /Users in
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php
>   on line 49

It seems that Doctrine2 doesn't like `'WITH', 'USER.eventNotified = FRIENDS.eventNotified'` for some reason. I don't really understand why. without this bit of code, the code works fine but this condition is indeed not fulfilled.

Many Thanks for your help

EDIT2:

After trying what was in the third comment of the answer below, I still get a similar error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException'
>   with message 'SELECT USER, FRIENDS, EVENT, c, p FROM Entity\User USER
>   LEFT JOIN USER.friends FRIENDS WHERE USER = :user AND
>   USER.eventNotified = FRIENDS.eventNotified' in
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:39Stack
>   trace:#0
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(429):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError('SELECT USER, FR...')#1
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(528):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->semanticalError(''EVENT' is not ...',
>   Array)#2
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(233):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->_processDeferredIdentificationVariables()#3
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(304):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->getAST()#4 /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfrien
>   in
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php
>   on line 49

I think we cannot do dynamic conditions. I don't know if there is a way to do it with doctrine otherwise I'll probably have to do that with PHP i guess ..

Here are the structure of my event and user entity:

User entity:

```
class User {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, unique=true)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fb_id", type="bigint", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $fb_id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=100, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $first_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=100, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $last_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="notation", type="integer", nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $notation;

    /**
     * Bidirectional - Many users have Many favorite comments (OWNING SIDE)
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Category", inversedBy="userInterests")
     */
    private $interests;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="friends",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/
    private $friends;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Request", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $requests;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Request", mappedBy="friend", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $notifications;

    /**
     * Bidirectional - Many users have notified they want to go to different events (OWNING SIDE)
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Event", inversedBy="userNotified", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $eventNotified;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="age", type="integer", length=3, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $age;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="picture", type="string", length=300, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $picture;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="genre", type="string", length=10, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $genre;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isregistered", type="boolean", length=1, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $registered;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="decimal", length=64, precision=25, scale=20, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $latitude;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="longitude", type="decimal", length=64, precision=25, scale=20, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $longitude;

    /**
     * @var \Entity\Security_Key
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Entity\Security_Key", cascade={"persist","remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="private_key_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     * })
     */
    private $private_key;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isavailable", type="boolean", length=1, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $available = 0;
```

Event entity:

```
class Event
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=200, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Category", inversedBy="events")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="categories_events")
     */
    private $categories;


    /**
     * @var \Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity\User", inversedBy="events")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $user;


    /**
     * @var \Entity\Admin
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity\Admin", inversedBy="events")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="admin_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $admin;

    /**
     * @var \Entity\Place
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity\Place", inversedBy="events", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $place;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="link", type="string", length=200, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $link;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="picture", type="string", length=100, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $picture;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_created", type="datetime", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_start", type="datetime", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $dateStart;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_end", type="datetime", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $dateEnd;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="confirmed", type="boolean", length=1, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $confirmed;

     /**
     * Bidirectional - One-To-Many (INVERSE SIDE)
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Request", mappedBy="event")
     */
    private $invitations;

    /**
     * Bidirectional - Many users are intending many events (INVERSE SIDE)
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="eventNotified", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $userNotified;
```

Comment: What is wrong with your results? Maybe use innerJoin on friends?

Comment: I don't know where to put the innerjoin on friend. I'm not retrieving the correct set of results ..

Comment: Maybe change this `->leftJoin('USER.friends', 'FRIENDS')` to `->innerJoin('USER.friends', 'FRIENDS')`?

Comment: hmm no, cause it will only select the users who have friends, but every users has friends, and I'm already specifying where User.id = userid

Comment: That makes sense. So are you getting users that don't match at all, or are you getting duplicates results? Also maybe post the relevant parts of your schema. That may be helpful to others.

Comment: will do, I'm trying different things, will update my researches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ideas:

You can try using something like `$qb->expr()->eq('FRIENDS.eventNotified', 'USER.eventNotified')` instead of `$qb->expr()->eq('FRIENDS.eventNotified.id', 'USER.eventNotified.id')`, because I suppose that eventNotified is someway a USER related entity which attribute name in your USER entity is eventNotified.

Anyhow, I would directly use a "with" in the join, so you limit your join results independently of your where clause:

```
  ->leftJoin('USER.friends', 'FRIENDS', 'WITH', 'FRIENDS.eventNotified = USER.eventNotified') // I'm going to take all of his friends
```

Bonus: should I also specify I want to retrieve 'c' and 'p' in the SELECT statement ?
Answer : yes, if you want to retrieve them with your getters after without a new query to the database

Comment: very helpful, let me try this one :)

Comment: I've tried your solution which seems to be what I need but I can't get around the error message you see in my edit ..

Comment: It might not work with dynamic "with" (not fixed values) or with self-referencing associations, I can not be sure without testing it or making a deeper research. Could you try this and if you have some errors, write here your apache logs/your exceptions? :

    `$qb->select( 'USER', 'FRIENDS' ) 
        ->from( 'Entity\User',  'USER' )
        ->where( 'USER = :user' )
        ->leftJoin('USER.friends', 'FRIENDS') 
        ->andWhere('USER.eventNotified = FRIENDS.eventNotified')`

Could you also write the basics of your entities ? That is, the affected attributes: eventNotified, friends...

Comment: just tried it, no success. I think you're right and that I should verify this condition with PHP maybe .. Now that I know where is the problem coming from, I'm thinking maybe I should create a more specific post about this problem (dynamic WITH and doctrine2 .. ?)

Comment: I think you should first revise your entities and the associations inside them. Using "with" or the where should be the same, I'd proposed it only cos it's more readable.

So: What kind of association do you have between User and EventNotified? If it's oneToMany, try: 

 `$qb->select( 'USER', 'FRIENDS' ) 
    ->from( 'Entity\User', 'USER' ) 
    ->where( 'USER = :user' )
    ->leftJoin ('User.eventNotified', 'UserEvent' ) 
    ->leftJoin('USER.friends', 'FRIENDS')
    ->leftJoin ('FRIENDS.eventNotified', 'FriendsEvevnt')
    ->andWhere('UserEvent.id = FriendEvent.id')`

Comment: Anyhow, as I told u, it would be easier to help u if you give me more information about your entities (right now I'm working with you blindly). If you have some errors in your Apache logs, post them too. If you got an Exception, post it. ;)

Comment: I've posted my entities as you asked (See edit), and the entire error message is right above it.

Comment: Can you try the query I wrote to you in my last comment here and the output error for that one ? I see that your relationship between User and eventNotified is manyToMany, so it's mandatory to have the joins with eventNotified for both User and Friend. In the exception that you described in "edit2", you do not have them.